# Android Studio game running slower on newer devices and faster on older devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation, lag

When testing my app on my Samsung A5 phone, it runs significantly slower than when I run it on my friend's Samsung S3 phone. Both phones had no other apps running in the background and are running the exact same app. How come my newer phone ran much slower than my friend's older phone?

Comment: Do the newer devices have higher screen resolution?

Comment: `Upon emulating my game on several different devices` -  test on real devices for performance, all your doing is testing how well an emulator works on your computer.

Comment: I did so with  several of my friend's phones. I appear to have similar results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because older models are easier to emulate on your computer.  Try using the actual phones and see if you get the same effect.

Comment: Yeah. They take less memory and the worse quality (Im assuming) makes it easier to emulate. +1

Comment: Ah thank you! This may likely be the case. Though when running it on my own 
 phone which is a lot newer than some of my emulated phones it actually still runs a bit slower. Could be because of another background process running on my phone when testing it? Or would it play on my phone as though I downloaded it from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe newer ones have high resolution displays and you use a lot of high quality pictures)

Comment: I'm actually using pixel art. So i feel as though the quality of my pictures has minimal effect on the speed difference

Comment: Be sure it has)